# Changing the column length will delete the column

Tags: typeorm

my class:

```
@Entity()
export class UserMemeber extends BsEntity {
  @Index({ unique: true })
  @Column({
    length:11
  })
  userId: string;
}
```

Whenever I change the length, typeorm will delete and recreate the column, and the data will be lost! Is there something wrong with my settings? What if I want to change the length while I use synchronization?

Comment: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md

Answer (score 2):

@Jared Farrish Thank you for your reply.

I mean, change the length of the column. Why delete the column? Even with migration, the data is lost.

```
export class article implements MigrationInterface {

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
        await queryRunner.query("ALTER TABLE `article` DROP COLUMN `name`");//lost data
        //why not this:ALTER TABLE `article` MODIFY  `name` varchar(33) NOT NULL
        await queryRunner.query("ALTER TABLE `article` ADD `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL");
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
        await queryRunner.query("ALTER TABLE `article` DROP COLUMN `name`");
        await queryRunner.query("ALTER TABLE `article` ADD `name` varchar(12) NOT NULL");//
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how typeorm is designed, I think it is a bad design, this is their answer to issue：[Migration generation drops and creates columns instead of altering resulting in data loss](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3357)